# A question about Euclidean domains

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, euclidean-domain

An integral domain $R$ is a Euclidean domain if there is a degree function $$\deg : R-\{0\} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}  $$ such that

- For every $a,b\in R$ with $b\ne 0$ there are $q,r\in R$ such that $$ a=bq+r$$ in which either $r=0$ or $\deg(r)<\deg(b)$.
- For every **nonzero** $a,b\in R$ we have $\deg(a)\le \deg(ab)$.

Now the question is:

Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain with degree function $\deg$. Is it true that in the division algorithm $$ a=bq+r$$
we can always **choose** some remainder $r$ so that either $a-r=0$ or $\deg (a-r) \le \deg a$ ?

This is certainly not true of all possible remainders in a division, but for example in $\mathbb{Z}$ there is always at least one remainder with the above property. The same is true about the ring of polynomials over a field $F[x]$ and the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. So is it true in any Euclidean domain? Or are there any counterexamples? And if so, is there any extra property of the domain or its degree function that guarantees the existence of such remainders (for example $\deg$ being multiplicative)?

**Edit:** I included the definition of Euclidean domains for more clarity. Also, the degree function is not required to be defined at $0$, so the trivial case of $r=a$ and $q=0$ is mentioned separately.

Comment: What do you require of $\deg$? (Different authors impose rather different axioms.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg That in the division $\deg r < \deg b$ or $r=0$. And $\deg(a)\le \deg(ab)$.

Comment: I don't think it's true for $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-2}\right]$ then, with the usual Euclidean norm (= square of the absolute value). If you look at the four radius-$1$ circles covering the fundamental domain (a rectangle with sidelengths $1$ and $\sqrt 2$), you will see that all four circles are needed (no three cover the whole domain), so that $a-r$ might be further away from the origin than $a$.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I should have emphasized that in $\deg a \le \deg (ab)$ both $a,b$ are nonzero.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you. If you can turn your comment into an answer I will accept it. Including a concrete example would be nice too; I think $a=1+\sqrt 2 i$ and $b=1-\sqrt 2 i$ will work (the remainders are $r=-1$ and $r=-\sqrt2 i$).

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by the *degree* of an integer.

Comment: [This](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~andrew/notes/abstracts/2009c.html) paper may be useful.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Thanks, it is interesting.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The degree of an integer is its absolute value.

Comment: @PaceNielsen $q$ is zero in your argument, so it does not work. $N(\cdot )$ is just $|\cdot |$ for integers; this should clarify what goes wrong in the argument.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep this question open, as I'm curious which quadratic rings $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ satisfy this stronger version of Euclideanness.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Can you make your example work with *any* Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$?

Comment: I don't understand why you say this is true for $F[x]$. If $a(x) = a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$ and $b(x) = x$, then there is only one choice for $q$ and $r$: We must take $q(x) = a_n x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_2 x + a_1$ and $r(x) = a_0$. Then $\deg(a-r) = \deg(a)=n$. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @PaceNielsen: Alas I don't have a good approach to understanding *all* Euclidean norms on a ring...

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Note that Mohammad only requires a *nonstrict* inequality $\deg(a-r)\leq \deg(a)$.

Comment: @PaceNielsen Thanks!